# Python - IndexError cannot fit 'long' into an index-sized integer

Tags: python-2.7

My code is working for small test cases but this is showing

***IndexError: cannot fit 'long' into an index-sized integer***

when I am using large numbers.

```
global mod
mod = 1000000007
global lim
lim = 10010
global cnt
cnt = [[None for x in range(0,4)] for x in range(0,lim+1)]
def precomp():
    cnt[2][0] = cnt[2][1] = cnt[2][2] = 1
    for i in range(3,lim):
        cnt[i][0] = cnt[i-1][2] % mod
        cnt[i][1] = cnt[i-1][0] % mod
        cnt[i][2] = (cnt[i-1][2] + cnt[i-1][1]) % mod

t = input()
precomp()
for iterate in range( t ):
   n = long(raw_input())
   print long((cnt[n][0] + cnt[n][1] + cnt[n][2]) % mod)
```

When I test case with following input:

2

2

3

But when I am using following input:

3

28488106923106212

18451226948892907

5082944357138639

It is showing an error. What are the other ways I can set size of the 2D list or can overcome this error? By changing the range from(0,4) not giving the error but it is taking very long time.

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to access `cnt[28488106923106212]` when `cnt` is a list of length `lim+1 = 10011`?

Comment: @ Janne my bad! should've thought that! thanks a lot